# This website declined to show this web page

Tags: migration, my-site, mysite, 403

I have recently migrated my sites from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013. I have done this by attaching the 2010 content database in  to SQL, creating a new web application and then mounting the content database. Once the content database was mounted I was then able to upgrade each site collection.

The migration appears to have run successfully as users content is available such as documents etc... however I am finding that if I search for a user and navigate to the users mysite then select "Apps" from the quick links I see the following page:
[image: My Site Issue]

If anyone could please provide some help or guidance on why this might be happening then it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried steps mentioned here?...https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/praveenh/2013/04/30/intermittent-http-403-forbidden-error-while-trying-to-browse-to-a-sharepoint-web-app/

Comment: I have tried this but still not luck. I have used a fiddler trace however as they do and I can see that I first get a 401 error then I get a 403 error.

Comment: Let me search something for you & will get back to you soon